# ie 8 and running web page from localmachine

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

Im developing a simple html contents page to go on a cd.  Im having problems navigating to the pages through the links on the contents page.  chrome navigates fine but ie 8 wont open the pages.  heres my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Gunnerbury Park Mansion</title>
    <!-- add meta tags -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Content page for LAM scan of Gunnersbury Mansion" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Gunnersbury mansion, LAM, Laser Aided Modelling, scan" />
    <meta name="rating" content="Safe for Kids" /> 
    <meta name="author" content="Richard Banks" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vertical-centering-page-layout.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ez-bg-resize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/transify-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Floater"></div>
    <div id="MainWrapper">
        <div id="Content">
            <div id="Header">Gunnerbury Park Mansion</div>
            <div id="ContentBody">
                <table id="Truviews">
                    <thead></thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td><a href="">External View</a></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><a href="Basement/SiteMap.htm">Basement View</a></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><a href="">Ground Floor View</a></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><a href="">First Floor View</a></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><a href="">Second Floor View</a></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><a href="">Roof View</a></td></tr>
                        <tr><td></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><a href="Truview software/TruViewSetup_2_1_0_1.exe">Install Truview 2.1</a></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><a href="Truview software/TruViewSetup221.exe">Upgrade to Truview 2.2</a></td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="Footer">
                <img src="EalingLogo.png" alt="Ealing Logo" alt="Ealing Logo" id="EalingLogo"/>
                <img src="GiffordLogo.png" alt="Gifford Logo" alt="Gifford Logo" id="GiffordLogo"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this is.  Ive read about the "mark of the web" but adding the decleration doesnt seem to change anything

Answer (score 0):

There is a slightly evil method which appears to work in IE.  I can't take credit for this though, this was offered by the gods of the internet.

```
<a href="C:\\Program Files\\Application\\Software.exe" onclick="return LaunchApp();">Launch the executable</a>

<script>
function LaunchApp() {
    if (!document.all) {
        // -- If we're not in IE, just go ahead with the normal loading routine.
        return true;
    }

    // -- If we're in IE, use ActiveX instead!
    var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    ws.Exec("C:\\Program Files\\Application\\Software.exe");
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: i only want the exe's offered as a download.  I dont want to run them.  Also the link to Basement/SiteMap.htm doesnt work.